# Change Featured image location from side to normal using react (gutenberg)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to move the Featured image panel in admin from side to under content position.
I've found how to do it with php but it isn't working when Gutenberg is being used.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339436/removing-panels-meta-boxes-in-the-block-editor
Here is an explanation of how to remove a block in Block Editor, but it isn't what I need.

Comment: It will probably not be the most clever way, but you can just move it with JS: `document.getElementById('normal-sortables').appendChild(document.getElementsByClassName("editor-post-featured-image")[0].parentElement)
`

Answer (score 0):

So it's duct tape solution but it does what I need.
Posting here my solution for the future me or the new generation.
Need to add a delay and wait until the feature image where be added to the page.
Thanks, @SamuelKrempaský for the tip!

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
  function admin_editor_scripts() {
    $script = "
    jQuery( window ).on('load', function() {
      let timerMoveFeatureImage = setInterval(function(){
        let featureBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('editor-post-featured-image');
        if (featureBlock.length > 0) {
          clearInterval(timerMoveFeatureImage);
          document.getElementById('normal-sortables').prepend(document.getElementsByClassName('editor-post-featured-image')[0].parentElement);
        }
      }, 1000);
    });";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-blocks', $script );
  }
  add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'admin_editor_scripts' );
}
```